# How to concatenate error message in Update Statement

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a script that does some validation, then updates some columns with the results.In the result, there is an error message column which is meant to be a human readable error message.  Since there is more than one column that could be invalid, the error message can be different.

I did the below using a varible, but I think that using a variable is not a good idea here.  Is there a better way to do this?

```
 declare @ErrorMessage nvarchar(100);

 ;WITH _UPDATE_ as
 (
 Select CsrNum 
   ,Substring(CsrNum, 2, 10) as CdsCsrId 
   ,IsNumeric(Substring(CsrNum, 2, 10)) as [CdsCsrIdIsNumeric]
   ,case when IsNumeric(Substring(CsrNum, 2, 10)) = 1 then (Select CsrId from Csr c where c.CdsCsrId = Substring(l.CsrNum, 2, 10)) 
   Else null
   end as ConvertedCsrId
   ,PortalCsrid
   ,PlankLoadStatusId
   ,ErrorMessage
   ,PlankLoadStatusDate
   ,(Select Code from State where Code = l.OrderCust_StateCode) as ValidatedStateCode

    from OrdercustPlankLoad l
   Where PlankLoadStatusId = 1
  )
    Update _UPDATE_ set 
   @ErrorMessage += case when  ValidatedStateCode is null then 'StateCode is invalid; ' else null end
  ,@ErrorMessage += case when ConvertedCsrId is null then 'CsrNum is Invalid; ' end
  ,ErrorMessage = @ErrorMessage
  , PortalCsrId = ConvertedCsrId
  , PlankLoadStatusId = case when @ErrorMessage is not null 
   then 4 --Error
   else 2 -- Validated
   end
  ,PlankLoadStatusDate = GetUTCDate()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about trying something like this:

```
;WITH _UPDATE_ AS (

    SELECT 
        CsrNum 
        , SUBSTRING ( CsrNum, 2, 10 ) AS CdsCsrId 
        , ISNUMERIC ( SUBSTRING ( CsrNum, 2, 10 ) ) AS [CdsCsrIdIsNumeric]
        , CASE 
            WHEN ISNUMERIC ( SUBSTRING ( CsrNum, 2, 10 ) ) = 1 THEN 
                ( SELECT CsrId FROM Csr c WHERE c.CdsCsrId = SUBSTRING ( l.CsrNum, 2, 10 ) ) 
            ELSE NULL
        END AS ConvertedCsrId
        , PortalCsrid
        , PlankLoadStatusId
        , ErrorMessage
        , PlankLoadStatusDate
        , ( SELECT Code FROM [State] WHERE Code = l.OrderCust_StateCode ) AS ValidatedStateCode
    FROM OrdercustPlankLoad l
    WHERE
        PlankLoadStatusId = 1

)
UPDATE _UPDATE_
SET
    ErrorMessage = CASE
        WHEN ValidatedStateCode IS NULL AND ConvertedCsrId IS NULL THEN 'StateCode is invalid; CsrNum is Invalid;'
        WHEN ValidatedStateCode IS NULL THEN 'StateCode is invalid;'
        WHEN ConvertedCsrId IS NULL THEN 'CsrNum is Invalid;'
        ELSE NULL
    END
    , PortalCsrId = ConvertedCsrId
    , PlankLoadStatusId = CASE
        WHEN ValidatedStateCode IS NULL OR ConvertedCsrId IS NULL THEN 4 --Error
        ELSE 2 -- Validated
    END
    , PlankLoadStatusDate = GETUTCDATE();
```